# Segmentation fault when initializing 2D array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I am declaring a 2d array in a headers file like this : int **arr;
Then I'm allocating memory and I initialize it with zeros. 
However I'm getting segmentation fault.

Here is my code :

```
arr = (int **)malloc(d * sizeof(int *)); 
for (int u=0; u<d; u++) 
    arr[u] = (int *)malloc(q * sizeof(int)); 
for(int i=0; i<d+1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<q+1; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `j<q+1` no. Check your bounds.

Comment: What is the purpose of `arr`?

Comment: Are you mixing up `scoreBoard` and `arr`? What is `scoreboard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation fault because you are overstepping the array's bounds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < d + 1; i++)
```

Should become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
```

And similarly for the other one. Don't forget array indices go from 0 to 1 less than the size (in elements) of the array.

Also:

Was the memory for scoreboard allocated? Currently, you create an array called `arr` rather than for the scoreboard you are initializing, so `scoreboard[u]` may also be out of bounds regardless of the value of u.

Comment: `scoreBoard[u]` may be out of boundaries too

Answer (score 2):

d+1 and q+1 both outside the boundary.
Use d and q

If you want to initialize with zero use **calloc()** which is simple to use and reduces redundant operations

```
arr = (int **)malloc(d * sizeof(int *)); 
for (int u=0; u<d; u++) 
    scoreBoard[u] = (int *)calloc(q , sizeof(int));
```

This code will create 2d int array and initialize with zero